# database query c# where clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have a database of this:

[image]

I need to select the **highest** value in a column. Currently I am using this query but it wont work:

```
string qry = @"select hawkername, address, postal, xcoord, ycoord, popularity from uploadphoto where MAX(popularity) ";
```

can someone guide me this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just order by popularity and limit to 1

```
select hawkername, address, postal, xcoord, ycoord, popularity 
from uploadphoto 
order by popularity DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f3673/2)

**Edit**
You've tagged your question incorrectly - you are using sql server.

```
select TOP 1 hawkername, address, postal, xcoord, ycoord, popularity 
from uploadphoto 
order by popularity DESC;
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f367/2)

Comment: had this error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near &#39;LIMIT&#39;.

Comment: Um, is this mysql or sql-server?

Comment: I am using a web service c# to connect to azure sql database